# How to use Regex Conditional OR statement within karate match contains?

Tags: regex, conditional-statements, karate

I've been using Conditional OR within match contains for a json validation in the below format.
I wanted to now use the #regex within this match contains and along with || (conditional OR). But this is not working, since `#regex` doesn't work inside JS syntax used for conditional OR here. What is other ways to do this?
This is working fine.

```
* match each testJson contains ({form: "#? _ == 'json' || _ == 'pdf'"})
```

I wanna do something like this,

```
* match each testJson contains ({form: "#? _ == '#regex .*success.json' || _ == '#regex .*pending.json'"})
```